# Different configurations for PHP CLI and Apache

Tags: php, openssl

I have a PHP installation and when I check the phpinfo using `php -i` from the command line, it is showing that the OpenSSL extension is installed. But when I use `phpinfo()` and access the file in browser, it is not showing openSSL extension there. Both are using the same `php.ini` file and `openssl.so` is there in the extension path specified. How can I enable this extension for the browser requests also ? I need to this because when I try to open a remote while which uses `https`, it is showing an error which says

```
Warning: fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I have tried in include the `openssl.so` by adding `extension=openssl.so` to the `.ini` file and restarted Apache. This is also not working.

Comment: _“Both are using the same php.ini file”_ - is that an assumption, or did you actually verify that?

Comment: I have verified this. Both are using `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `php -i` is called from command line, it will show the particulars of PHP Command Line (CLI), where as when you access a webpage, the PHP module for Apache will come into play. I have been re-compiling PHP with only `--with openssl` and it was affecting only the command line version. Now for fixing the issue, I have compiled using `./configure' '--with-openssl' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-apxs2=/bin/apxs`. Issue is fixed now